# How to plot a vector in matlab with another vector as a parameter?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to optimize the speed of a function I am writing, and trying to use vectors as much as I can. I am new to Matlab and vectorization is sometimes understandable to me, but I would like some additional help. Here is my current code:

For note, the oracle() function represents a randomly shaped object, and if you input a 1x2 matrix, it will return whether or not the matrx (or in our case, x- y-coordinates) is inside the random object.

[Code In Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fziv.png)

```
function area = MitchellLitvinov_areaCalc(n)
    % create random coordinate vectors, with bounds from (3, 14)
    x = rand(n, 1) * 11 + 3;
    y = rand(n, 1) * 11 + 3;

    % find every point that is inside of oracle
    inOracle = oracle([x y]);

    % calculate the proportion, and multiply total area by proportion to find area
    % of oracle
    numPointsInOracle = nnz(inOracle);
    area = numPointsInOracle/n * (11*11);

    % create variable to store number of points in the area, and create a
    % matrix with size [numPoints, 2] to hold x and y values
    oracleCoordinates = zeros(numPointsInOracle, 2);

    % HERE IS WHERE I NEED ASSISTANCE!!!!!!!!!
    % find the points that are in the oracle shape
    index = 0; % start index at 0 % is the index of our oracleCoordinates matrix
    for i = 1:n % have to go through every point again to get their index

        % if point is inside oracle, increase index and record
        % coordinates
        if (inOracle(i) == 1) % see if point is in oracle
            index = index + 1; 
            oracleCoordinates(index, 1) = x(i, 1);
            oracleCoordinates(index, 2) = y(i, 1);
        end
    end

    % plot all points inside the oracle
    scatter(oracleCoordinates(:,1), oracleCoordinates(:,2))
    title("Oracle Shape")
    xlim([3, 14]);
    ylim([3, 14]);
end
```

Yes, even with near maximum memory usage, the code will run fairly quickly. But I want it to be fully vectorized simply for speed reasons, and if I need to repurpose this code for imaging. Currently, to calculate the area I am using vectors, but to actually reproduce an image, I need to create a separate storage matrix, and manually use indexing/appending to then transfer over the points inside the oracle function. I was wondering if there were any direct "shortcuts" to make my plotting a bit faster.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to check out the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better answers if you post code that other people can run. A picture of code is not helpful, but a picture of a plot might be :) And it seems like this question is about vectorization, and not specific to plotting, i.e., the plot statement takes the same amount of time, regardless of how the vector is created.

Comment: Preallocating the array will speed up your code. Vectorizing it doesn’t necessarily speed it up. Don’t assume that avoiding loops is always good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array as the index to select certain items from another array. For example, using your variable names:

```
oracleCoordinates(:,1) = x(inOracle == 1);
oracleCoordinates(:,2) = y(inOracle == 1);
```

This should give the same result as the code in your question, without using a loop.

Comment: for what it's worth, if `inOracle` is already a logical array, you can do the same but just `x(inOracle)`

Comment: Thank you so much to you both! 
mhopeng, the suggestion definitely made my code cleaner. I'm still trying to understand vectorization, and this really helped! The performance is amazing.
For Wolfie, I thought it would have been a logical array but it wasn't unfortunately. But regardless thank you!